# IPv6 delete route

Tags: ipv6

Some times ago I played around with the IPv6 routes and I made confusion :) That is my routing table

```
root@banana:~# route -6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d00::/64        ::                         UAe  256 0     0 eth0
2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01::/64        ::                         UAe  256 0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         U    1   0     0 eth0
::/0                           fe80::20f:34ff:feac:fa49   UGDAe 1024 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1 73439 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1 15647 lo
2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d00:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc/128 ::                         Un   0   1  3615 lo
2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc/128 ::                         Un   0   1   678 lo
fe80::d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc/128  ::                         Un   0   1 17417 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1 73439 lo
```

Basically, I want just the default against eth0 and remove the remaining against loopback

When I try to delete them I get this error

```
root@banana:~# route -A inet6 del default via fe80::20f:34ff:feac:fa49
Usage: inet6_route [-vF] del Target
       inet6_route [-vF] add Target [gw Gw] [metric M] [[dev] If]
       inet6_route [-FC] flush      NOT supported
root@banana:~# route -A  inet6_route del default via fe80::20f:34ff:feac:fa49
Unknown address family `inet6_route'.
```

Now, I want clean my routing table because seems that my server has not a route

```
root@banana:~# ping6 2001:4860:4860::8888
PING 2001:4860:4860::8888(2001:4860:4860::8888) 56 data bytes
From 2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc icmp_seq=5 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc icmp_seq=6 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc icmp_seq=7 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
^C
--- 2001:4860:4860::8888 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 8999ms
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

I would try

```
ip -6 route del 2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc dev lo0
```

or

```
route -A inet6 del 2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc
```

obviously `2a02:c7d:ca1b:6d01:d250:99ff:fe53:f2fc` is an external host (mac being `d0:50:90:53:f2:fc` ), its traffic shound not get routed to `lo0`.